# batch rename files

Tags: filesystems, filenames

I have multiple photo files with inconsistent name format.

- beach north.JPG
- beach south sm.jpg
- Bryce windsurfing sm.jpg
- DSC01031 1024x.jpg
- DSC02652 ed sm.jpg
- DSC03229 sm.jpg
- Kayak kids 2.jpg
- Maui 5-05 (31) 1024.jpg
- Maui fall 05 (41) sm.jpg
- maui whale (2) sm.jpg
- maui whale (6) ed.jpg
- P1000018 sm.jpg
- P1000030 sm.jpg
- P1000056 sm.jpg
- P1000148 sm.jpg
- P1000397 sm.jpg
- P1000490 sm.jpg
- P1000629 sm.jpg
- P1000995 sm.jpg
- P1010006 1024.jpg
- P1010089 1024x.jpg
- P1050988 ed sm.jpg

I don't want to rename the extensions, but rename the first .jpg on the list as 1.jpg, second 2.jpg, third 3.jpg, etc. How do I do this with one command?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Just use a loop in the shell:

```
for x in * ; do mv -- "$x" "$((i=i+1)).jpg" ; done
```

We look at each file in the current directory one at a time, calling it `x`, and then move it to `$i.jpg`, where we increment `$i` by one each time. `$((...))` is [arithmetic expansion](https://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/bashref.html#Arithmetic-Expansion), and assignments return the value assigned, so this both modifies `i` and returns the new number each time around.

If you're going to do this more than once, say in different directories, you'll want to reset the counter in between: just say `i=0`, or put `i=0;` at the start of the command.

Comment: This is what I was thinking would be a solution. Let's see if I can get it to work. I'm new to programming, and have been doing it seriously for only a few months. I've only made C program files and ran them on the command line. I had no idea you could run programs in the shell...

Comment: It worked! Thank you! I searched the web for a bit and could only find things on changing file extensions and removing/changing file names if they were all named consistently.

Comment: @TylerZika - if this A solved your issue please mark it as accepted so everyone knows your issue's been resolved.

Comment: Note that it can potentially lose files if there are some called like `1.jpg` already. You may want to add `-i` or better use `zsh`'s `zmv` instead which checks for those conditions _before_ starting to rename.